# Get SMS Message ID before send SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I have a requirement, where I would need to get SMS Message ID before the SMS gets sent out.

I know that post SMS activated, we can able to send it. But I would need before it gets sent.

Like how we have Email Id, I would need SMS Message ID. Is there any way to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the dataview doc: [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5)

> Identify the name of the SMS message that you want to check on the MobileConnect Overview page.
>
> To retrieve the MessageID, click the message name.
>
> 1. On the message Overview page, note the URL:
> 2. Copy the Base64 encoded text.
> 3. Use an online Base64 decoder to decode the Base64 encoded text.
> 4. The result appears in this format: 65:78:0 5. Based on this result,the MessageID for this message is 65.
>
> Sample URL: https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/MobileConnect/Mobile/%23!/message/view/NjU6Nzg6MA
>
> Sample Base64 encoded text: NjU6Nzg6MA

Comment: Hi @Eazy thanks for your response. We can get this info Journey Builder SMS is active. But I would need to get the SMS Message ID even before its active like how we can get the Email ID. Is there any way?

Comment: The mobile message ID doesn’t exist till it’s created in mobile studio. They do increase numerically without the MID. So if your last message was 9 your next message will be 10

Comment: Thanks for your response @EazyE, yes i understand but seems like no way to retrieve the SMS Message ID before SMS gets sent.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see this being done, is somehow you can pull the dependency of the short code. Because when you see the short code under the administration view, you see all the messages (even when the message is in drafts). But it seems like it is not possible. The only turn around could be, if you could do a test send on the message you created and then check the [_SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=5) view. There is a field **IsTest** which can help you identify the send and hence the SMS Id before the actual dispatch.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Swati! ya this can be a workaround when you send a test from Mobile connect. But from Journey builder or automation studio seems to be difficult:(